# How to change MPM prefork to worker on default Apache OSX installation?

Tags: macos, apache, osx-lion

How to change MPM prefork to worker on default Apache OSX installation?

for example, on centOS, the configuration can be found in /etc/sysconfig/httpd

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While apache installation; On running the Configure, include the option --with-mpm=worker

i.e 
./configure --with-mpm=worker
followed by,
'make' and 'make install'

Refer to the following link for more info:
http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/misc/perf-tuning.html